# How to draft a mail using javamail api in android?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use this:

```
public void saveDraftMessage(MimeMessage draftMessage, Store imapsStore) throws MessagingException
    {
        Folder draftsMailBoxFolder = imapsStore.getFolder("inbox");//[Gmail]/Drafts
        draftsMailBoxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        draftMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DRAFT, true);
        MimeMessage draftMessages[] = {draftMessage};
        draftsMailBoxFolder.appendMessages(draftMessages);

    }
```

Properties set up:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Session login:

```
session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userEmailId, password);
            }
        });
}
```

Calling from:

```
store = session.getStore("smtp");

store.connect(userEmailId, password);

MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

saveDraftMessage(mm,store);

store.close();
```

Now getting error is:

javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: invalid provider

at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:575)

at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:541)

at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:520)

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is not a store provider it is a transport provider.  You need to adjust all of your properties to connect to IMAP server:

Try one of the following:

```
store = session.getStore();
//store = session.getStore("imaps");
//store = session.getStore("imap");
```